# How to remove <br> and everything after that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do the following is fine:

```
<div id="results">
  <p>Hello<br>there</p>
</div>

$($("#results p").children('br').get(0).nextSibling).remove();
```

I get: `hello`

But if I do:

```
<th class="infobox">Head</th>
<td>Hello<br>there</td>

var newLineRemove = $(".infobox td").children('br').get(0).nextSibling();
$wikiDOM.find(newLineRemove).remove();
```

Gives me

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined

Comment: Is it because the `<td>` isn't inside the .`.infobox` therefore your selector `$(".infobox td")` isn't returning anything and therefore neither will your call to `.children('br')`?

Comment: @Forty3 yup saw that mistake but I won't change the question as there are 2 errors, one is that one you've mentioned, the other one is better explained in one of the answers below

Comment: `$($(".infobox").next("td").children("br")[0].nextSibling).remove()`

Comment: @nnnnnn nope https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1007/ you've got an error with )

Comment: So remove the extra `)`, it's not rocket science (I'd already edited my comment to do so). Your fiddle didn't work after that because you had TD and TH outside of a TABLE, so the browser doesn't treat them as TD and TH - put them in a TABLE with a TR and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/1018/

Comment: @nnnnnn excellent, could you put this into an answer and I will accept it? the other answer works too but your is more inline with the code provided, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the `".infobox td"` selector is looking for a td element *inside* an `.infobox` element, but in your HTML the td immediately follows the `.infobox`.

If you want something that is very similar to your existing JS but working with that HTML (noting that td and th elements need to be inside a tr in a table) you can do this:

```js
$($(".infobox").next().children("br")[0].nextSibling).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<th class="infobox"></th>
<td>Hello<br>there</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

That is, use `.next()` to get the element following the `.infobox`, get *that* element's child br elements, take the first one's `.nextSibling`, then wrap it in a jQuery object so that you can call `.remove()`.

EDIT: Note that if there were multiple rows with similar elements the above code would only do the removal on the first one. If it were my code I would probably select *all* of the relevant elements and then update their HTML something more like this:

```
$(".infobox").next("td").html(function(i, h) { return h.split('<br>')[0] })
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because `.get(...)` returns a DOM element not a jQuery object.
In the first example you're using `$(...)` to convert that DOM element to a jQuery object but you're not doing that in the second example.

This will convert the DOM element to a jQuery element and get rid of the error

```
var newLineRemove = $($(".infobox td").children('br').get(0).nextSibling);
```

But it won't do what you want it to do because as @Forty3 said *"the `<td>` isn't inside the ..infobox"*

This seems to work but I've probably made things more complicated then they have to be:

```js
$(function(){
  var td = $(".infobox").next();
  if(td.find("br").length){
    $(td.contents().get().reverse()).each(function(){
      $(this).remove();
      if(this.tagName == "BR"){
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<th class="infobox"></th>
<td>Hello<br>there</td>
</table>
```

Comment: i see, can you also provide a coding solution for future references and I will accept it please? Thanks

Comment: @rob.m What is `$wikiDOM` ?

Comment: it's just a var that I defined       `var wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
      var $wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");`

Comment: Using `.eq()` instead of `.get()` wrapped in `$()` would be neater. Also, `.nextSibling()` should be `.next()`.

Comment: see this fiddle and also careful that td isn't child of infobox as you've mentiend, https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/997/

Comment: it gives Uncaught TypeError: $(...).nextSibling is not a function

Comment: same error when doing `$($("td").children('br').get(0).nextSibling).remove();`

Comment: @rob.m Actually, I'm completely wrong here because I've just realised that `nextSibling` is a DOM element property not a jQuery function, the problem is the `$(".infobox td").children('br').get(0)` returns `undefined` because the selector is incorrect (doesn't return any elements).

Comment: same thing `$("td").children('br').get(0).nextSibling().remove();` https://jsfiddle.net/jikupin/pz3ce0o6/1004/

Comment: @rob.m To test this on **jsfiddle** you need to wrap all the elements into a `<table>` element, otherwise they will all be converted to just their test.

Comment: @nnnnnn From what I understand, the OP wants to remove the `<br>` and the text after it, that is why I've reversed the array and made the loop stop removing elements after the `<br>`

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, you're right but to account for those cases a check like `$($(".infobox").next().contents().get().reverse()).find("br").length > 0` will be required, all the elements will still be removed even if the `....remove()` is placed after the `if` statement.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I like it. (I'd like it even more if it allowed for hypothetical elements that don't have a `<br>` in them.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I've changed it to account for those cases.

Answer (score 2):

I've simplest solution for this, try this one:

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html().split('<br>')[0]);
});
```

```css
li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#usp-custom-3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="infobox"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hell
      <br>there</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello
      <br>there<br>there</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that this is overwriting all of the rows with the value from the first row. (Change the second row to "Hi" instead of "Hello" to see what I mean.) You can fix that by doing something like `$("td").html(function(i, h) { return h.split('<br>')[0] })`.